# Why is `trap -` not working when put inside a function?

Tags: bash

### Short version

In a Bash script, I activate a trap, and later deactivate it by calling `trap - EXIT ERR SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM`. When I do the deactivation directly in the script, it works. However, when I put the exact same line of code in a Bash function, it is ignored, i.e. the trap is still activated if, later, a command returns an exit code different from zero. Why?

### Long version

I have a bunch of functions to work with traps:

```
trap_stop()
{
    echo "trap_stop"
    trap - EXIT ERR SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
}

trap_terminate()
{
    local exitCode="$?"
    echo "trap_terminate"
    trap_stop

    local file="${BASH_SOURCE[1]}"
    local stack=$(caller)
    local line="${stack% *}"

    if [ $exitCode == 0 ]; then
        echo "Finished."
    else
        echo "The initialization failed with code $exitCode in $file:${line}."
    fi

    exit $exitCode
}

trap_start()
{
    echo "trap_start"
    trap "trap_terminate $LINENO" EXIT ERR SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
}
```

When used like this:

```
trap_start  # <- Trap started.

echo "Stopping traps."
trap_stop  # <- Trap stopped before calling a command which exits with exit code 2.

echo "Performing a command which will fail."
ls /tmp/missing
exit_code="$?"

echo "The result of the check is $exit_code."
```

I get the following output:

```
trap_start
Stopping traps.
trap_stop
Performing a command which will fail.
ls: cannot access '/tmp/missing': No such file or directory
trap_terminate
trap_stop
The initialization failed with code 2 in ./init:41.
```

Despite the fact that function deactivating the trap was called, the trap was still triggered when calling `ls` on a directory which doesn't exist.

On the other hand, when I replace the call to `trap_stop` by the actual `trap -` statement, like this:

```
trap_start

echo "Stopping traps."
trap - EXIT ERR SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM  # <- This statement replaced the call to `trap_stop`.

echo "Performing a command which will fail."
ls /tmp/missing
exit_code="$?"

echo "The result of the check is $exit_code."
```

then the output is correct, i.e. the trap is not activated and I reach the end of the script.

```
trap_start
Stopping traps.
Performing a command which will fail.
ls: cannot access '/tmp/missing': No such file or directory
The result of the check is 2.
```

Why is moving `trap -` to a function makes it stop working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** (courtesy of @KamilCuk): If your bash is older than 4.4, upgrade your bash, it could solve the problem.

---

I added some debugging to your code:

```
echo "Stopping traps."
trap -p
trap_stop  # <- Trap stopped before calling a command which exits with exit code 2.
trap -p
```

And got:

```
Stopping traps.
trap -- 'trap_terminate 29' EXIT
trap -- 'trap_terminate 29' SIGHUP
trap -- 'trap_terminate 29' SIGINT
trap -- '' SIGFPE
trap -- 'trap_terminate 29' SIGTERM
trap -- '' SIGXFSZ
trap -- '' SIGPWR
trap -- 'trap_terminate 29' ERR
trap_stop
trap -- '' SIGFPE
trap -- '' SIGXFSZ
trap -- '' SIGPWR
trap -- 'trap_terminate 29' ERR
```

As you can see, the `trap -` part does work, *except* for the `ERR` condition.

After some man page time:

```
echo "Stopping traps."
set -E
trap_stop  # <- Trap stopped before calling a command which exits with exit code 2.
```

yields:

```
trap_start
Stopping traps.
trap_stop
Performing a command which will fail.
ls: cannot access '/tmp/missing': No such file or directory
The result of the check is 2.
```

The relevant part of [`bash(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> -E
>   If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment. The ERR trap is normally not inherited in such cases.

That said, this seems to be a bug in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

t1()
{
    trap 'echo t1' ERR
}

t2()
{
    trap 'echo t2' ERR
}

t1
false
t2
false
```

yields:

```
t1
t1
```

whereas I'd expect at the very least:

```
t1
t2
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug , I get `t1 t2` on output. [repl agrees with me](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/PeacefulRegularArchives) and also outputs `t1 t2`. What bash version do you have?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Indeed, can reproduce in docker bash:4.3 . So seems it is fixed in bash 4.4

Comment: Okay, so the t1 t2 bug was fixed in bash 4.4 but `set -E` is still needed to make `trap - ERR` in a function effective. Got it.

Comment: Wait so, then that makes this part at the beginning of the answer really confusing: "EDIT (courtesy of @KamilCuk): If your bash is older than 4.4, upgrade your bash, it could solve the problem."

Comment: Also "this seems to be a bug in bash" could be interpreted as "the need for `set -E` to make `trap - ERR` work in a function seems to be a bug in bash", which I think is not true and not what you meant.